# Google App Maker: change calculated datasource Query page size programatically

Tags: google-app-maker

How do I change the query page size of a calculated model. I have it set to 10 by default but, upon a user searching for records that contain a specific string, I'd like to display all records and remove pagination. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this would be to set the page size to 0 on the client by doing the following (this is assuming you are directly referencing your datasource):

```
app.datasources.YourDatasource.query.pageSize = 0;
```

This is the client solution. If you where comparing specific string in your datasource Query Script or through another server script then it would be as follows:

```
query.limit = 0;
```

Hope this helps.